# Datetime in HQL check only date

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I've the following hql query:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Appointments where datetime < :now");
query.setDate("now", new Date());
listApps = query.list();
```

It return only the records before today (yesterday, 2 days ago and so on)
But not the record of today before than this time.

The datetime into the database is of type DateTime, so it contains both date and time.

Why is this query not returning the record of today before than the current time?

This is the way datetime is defined inside my entity:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date datetime;
```

Comment: How is your `datetime` field annotated? Have it `@Temporal` annotation? Is it `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date`?

Comment: It's a java.util.Date

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
query.setDate("now", new Date());
```

to

- `query.setTimestamp("now", new Date());`

or to:

- `query.setParameter("now", new Date());`

---

*Bind the date (**time is truncated**) of a given Date object to a named query parameter.*

```
public Query setDate(String name, Date date);
```

*Bind the date and the time of a given Date object to a named query parameter.*

```
public Query setTimestamp(String name, Date date);
```